# Handeling Cookie pop-up after page 6/7

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have build a webscraping for real estate data with the help of some fellowsmembers on this website.

It works perfectly, but after is crawls to page 6/7 or furhter, a cookie the typical cookie warning pop up, and seem to disrupt my output in my CSV file.

Is there a way to handle the pop up?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
#open('output.csv', 'w').close()

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/907133/Pythonstuff/chromedriver')
browser.set_window_position(0,0)

def jaap_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://www.jaap.nl/koophuizen/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterdam/p{}'.format(page)
        #browser.delete_all_cookies()
        browser.get(url)
        #session = requests.Session()
        #res1 = session.post(url, post_data)
        #res2 = session.get(url1)
        time.sleep(15)
        #input('Press Enter after bypassing Captcha')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
        info = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'property-info'})
        inside = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'property-inner'},{'href'})
    # Make empty lists with header lines
    outputlist_l1 = [['street', 'address', 'price', 'pricetag']]
    outputlist_l2 = [['soort', 'bouwjaar', 'woonoppervlakte', 'inhoud', 'perceel']]

    for huis in info:
        street = huis.find('h2')
        street = ' '.join(street.get_text(separator='\r\n', strip=True).split()[:+3])  
        address = huis.find('div')
        address = address.find('div').text.strip()
        price = huis.find('div', {'class': 'price-info'})
        price = price.find('div').text.strip()
        price = re.findall(r'\d', price)
        price = ''.join(price)
        pricetag = huis.find('div', {'class': 'property-price'})
        pricetag = pricetag.find('span').text.strip()
        outputlist_l1.append([street, address, price, pricetag])

    for items in inside:
        #browser.delete_all_cookies()
        href = items.get('href')
        url1 = href.format(page)
        browser.get(url1)
        kenmerken = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
        details = kenmerken.find_all ('div', {'class':'detail-tab-content kenmerken'})
        try:
            tr = details[0].find_all ('td', {'class': 'value'})
        except IndexError:
            size_space = 'Unknown'

        for inhoud in tr:
            soort = tr[0].get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)
            bouwjaar = tr[1].get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)
            woonoppervlakte = tr[2].get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)
            inhoud = tr[3].get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)
            perceel = tr[4].get_text(separator='\n', strip=True)
        l2 = ('{},{},{},{},{}'.format(soort, bouwjaar, woonoppervlakte, inhoud, perceel))
        outputlist_l2.append([soort, bouwjaar, woonoppervlakte, inhoud, perceel])

    page += 1    
# Merge outputlist_l1 with outputlist_l2
outputlist = [a + b for a, b in zip(outputlist_l1, outputlist_l2)]

# transform to Pandas dataframe and export as csv
#saveFile = open('output.csv', 'a')
df = pd.DataFrame(outputlist[1:], columns=outputlist[0])
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
#saveFile.close()

jaap_spider(15)
```

THe cookie script in the website:

(function(){function g(a){return{get:function(b){var c=JSON.parse(a.getItem(b));return!c||Date.parse(c.expires)<=(new Date).getTime()?(a.removeItem(b),null):c.value},set:function(b,c,d){c={value:c,expires:d.toUTCString()};a.setItem(b,JSON.stringify(c))},remove:function(b){a.removeItem(b)}}}function d(a,b,c,d){this.parseCommand=function(e,g){function h(){var a=JSON.stringify({messageId:k,value:l||!1});window.parent.postMessage(a,"*")}var m=q[a],n=e.action,p=e.key,k=e.messageId,f=e.siteId,f=d?p:p+":"+
f,l=e.value,r=e.expiresMinutes||1440*(e.expiresDays||365),s=function(){var a=new Date;a.setTime(a.getTime()+6E4*r);return a}();if(!function(){var a={_hjSet:c,_hjGet:b,_hjRemove:c}[n]||[];return 0<=a.indexOf("*")||0<=a.indexOf(g)}())throw Error("Command "+n+" not allowed on key: "+p);switch(n){case "_hjSet":m.set(f,l,s);break;case "_hjGet":l=m.get(f);h();break;case "_hjRemove":m.remove(f)}}}function h(a){try{var b=JSON.parse(a.data);b.key&&k[b.key]&&k[b.key].parseCommand(b,a.origin)}catch(c){return null}}
var q;try{q={cookie:{get:function(a){return(a=RegExp("(?:^|; )"+a+"=([^;]*)").exec(document.cookie))?a[1]:void 0},set:function(a,b,c){document.cookie=a+"="+b+"; path=/; expires="+c.toUTCString()},remove:function(a){document.cookie=a+"=; expires=Tue, 13 Mar 1979 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;"}},localStorage:g(localStorage),sessionStorage:g(sessionStorage)}}catch(t){return}var k={_hjOptOut:new d("cookie",["*"],["https://www.hotjar.com","https://local.hotjar.com","http://local.hotjar.com","https://insights-staging.hotjar.com",
"http://insights-staging.hotjar.com"],!0),grant_consent:new d("cookie",["*"],["*"],!1),screenshot_retake:new d("localStorage",["*"],["*"],!1),screenshot_active_retake:new d("sessionStorage",["*"],["*"],!1)};window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener("message",h,!1):window.attachEvent("onmessage",h)})();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome the pop up problem just check after loading the page if there any pop up available. If yes,then click on that.Hope this help.

```
page = 1
while page <= max_pages:
  url = 'https://www.jaap.nl/koophuizen/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterdam/p{}'.format(page)
  browser.get(url)
  time.sleep(10)
  #Check here if there popup available
  if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='CookiesOK']"))>0:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='CookiesOK']").click()
        time.sleep(5)
    #input('Press Enter after bypassing Captcha')
  soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
  info = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'property-info'})
  inside = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'property-inner'},{'href'})
```

Comment: This works!
but sometimes its keeps popping up again, meaning the script doesn't put it away. anything i can do in the script added above form the website?